# IntelliJ IDEA 'class' or 'interface' expected

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea, interface

```
public class StudentApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student1 = new Student("test");
        Student student2 = new Student("test","test");
        System.out.println(student2.getId());
    }
}
```

The constructor looks like this:

```
public Student(String firstName, String lastName){
        this.id=nextId++;
        this.name = firstName+" "+lastName;
    }
```

The first argument of student2 is saying "'class' or 'interface' expected" but it compiles and runs just fine. What may be the error here?

Comment: Looks like [this](https://imgur.com/fYuLQm2)

Comment: restarting the IDE helps?

Comment: No did not but I figured it out, see my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the Language Injections page: Editor | Language Injections and uncheck or delete the injection created by IDE.

Comment: I feel like you should try to "Invalidate Caches / Restart" first, accessed through the file menu

Answer (score 2):

This error is mainly cause by if extra parenthesis is present in code. Remove the extra parenthesis from your code.